# Pandas plot stacked and unstacked bar

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas. I am trying to visualize the time my program takes for different tasks.
I read my logs and calculated the average time, and it now looks like this:
[image]

As I have only one row, I need to draw these tree time values in a bar plot. **Time1** should be a single bar and **Time2** and **Time3** being combined. **Time3** is supposed to be on top of Time2 with a different color.
What i did so far is:

```
axis = time_pd.plot(kind='bar', ylabel="Time [sek]", xlabel="Phase", figsize=(11,11), rot=0)
legend = axis.legend(["time1", "time2", "time3"], fontsize=26, loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.93))
```

The result is 3 bars on only one label on the x-axis:
[image]

Can someone give me any advice how to set up 2 Bars with **Time1** and **Time2** with **Time3** being on top of **Time2**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to plot to figures and merge the result.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'time1':[3], 'time2':[2], 'time3':[1]})

ax = df['time1'].plot.bar(ylabel="Time [sek]", xlabel="Phase", figsize=(8,8), color='green', position=1)
df[['time2', 'time3']].plot.bar(stacked=True, sharex=True, ax=ax, position=0)
legend = ax.legend(["time1", "time2", "time3"], fontsize=12, loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.93))
plt.xlim([-1, 1])
plt.show()
```

**Output**

[image: bar plot with stacked part]

**Comment**

I use `pandas.plot` twice, the first time "plain" and the second time "stacked". This normally produces two figures. To have only one, I re-use the axis by `ax=ax` in the second call.

To avoid that both plots are on each other and the first can not be seen, I use the `position` keyword. The limits for the x-axis have to be set, too, or some parts of the plot are outside of the visual area.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That already looks really good. The finishing touch would be to let a little bit of space between those two columns and adding different x-tick-labels. I am trying things out right now, but if you also happen to know how to add this, it would be really nice.

Comment: For the space, you can play a bit with the `position`. You can set your x-ticks with [`ax.set_xticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks).